# NgRx Effect Not Firing

Tags: angular, ngrx, nrwl

Given this facade:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LookupDataFacade
{
    public saved$: Observable<boolean>;
    public loaded$: Observable<boolean>;
    public allLookups$: Observable<ILookup[]>;
    public selectedLookup$: Observable<ILookup>;

    constructor( protected store: Store<LookupDataPartialState> ) { }

    loadAll()
    {
        this.store.dispatch( new LoadLookupData() );
    }

    ...
}
```

And this effects class:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LookupDataEffects
{
    constructor(
        protected actions$: Actions,
        protected dataPersistence: DataPersistence<LookupDataPartialState>,
        protected service: LookupDataService ) { }

    @Effect()
    loadLookupData$ = this.dataPersistence.fetch<LoadLookupData>( LookupDataActionTypes.Load,
    {
        run: ( action: LoadLookupData, state: LookupDataPartialState ) =>
        {
            return this.service.get().pipe( map( lookups => ( {
                type: LookupDataActionTypes.Loaded,
                payload: { data: lookups }
            } ) ) );
        },

        onError: ( action: LoadLookupData, error: HttpErrorResponse ) => { this.handleError( error ); }
        } );

    ...

    handleError = function( error: HttpErrorResponse )
    {
        console.error( 'Error', error );
        alert( error.message );
        return new LookupDataError( error );
    }
}
```

When the page loads, the 'loadAll' method of the facade is called.  The action is dispatched but the appropriate effect never gets executed.

This code used to work before I upgraded my NgRx and Nrwl packages to the latest versions (needed to do this to resolve the 'Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function' fatal error I was getting).

I'm not seeing any errors and there is no network traffic that indicates a failure.

Anyone see a glaring error?

Comment: how is nrwl related to this?

Comment: I'm using the 'DataPersistence' class within the effect.  Not sure if it or something inside NgRx is preventing the effect from being called.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- `LookupDataEffects` is registered in the `EffectsModule.forFeature([])`
- `LookupDataActionTypes.Load` correctly maps to `new LoadLookupData`

Also there is a small error here:

```
onError: ( action: LoadLookupData, error: HttpErrorResponse ) => { this.handleError( error ); }
```

We have to either `=> this.handleError( error )` or `=> { return this.handleError( error ); }`

Also
`fetch<LoadLookupData>` should be `fetch<LoadedLookupData | LookupDataError >` (it's the return type of the actions that are possible to be dispatched in the Effect)

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  Although this didn't solve my problem, I did fix the errors you noted above.  Ultimately, I rolled the changes back to a previous version that worked and then re-implemented my code changes.  It is working again.